# Temporary Remove Flex Duct

Tags: hvac, basement, ducts, removal

I am about to replace a load bearing wall in unfinished basement.  There is flexible duct attached to plenum that I need to temporarily move out in order to put the beams in.  Do i just need to cut the tie and pull it off the collar and then re-install and re-tie it back once I get the beams in place?

Comment: Sounds about right, you may want to get some high quality duct tape to wrap the joints with.